# Requests.post() doing nothing

Tags: python, forms, request, fill

```
url = 'http://tres-bien.com/iewrhdh'

header = {
'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/64.0.3282.167 Chrome/64.0.3282.167 Safari/537.36'} # I'm using this to connect to the site , otherwise it's 405 Forbidden

payload = {

   'cm-name': 'Full Name' ,
   'cm-zltlkh-zltlkh': 'email@gmail.com' ,
   'cm-f-qhdyui': 'Shipping/billing address' ,
   'cm-f-qhdyud': 'Zipcode' ,
   'cm-f-qhdyuh': 'City' ,
   'cm-fo-qhdyuk': '3306989' ,
   'cm-f-qhdyuu': '0484741436' ,
   'cm-fo-qhdjlr': '3307095' 

}

# All the form that need to be fill , I used Chrome Console to see what is posted

r = requests.post(url , payload , headers=header)
print(r.text)
```

I was just wondering, why after running this script nothing is submitting. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Did r.text work?

Comment: Yes, but it's only showing the form of the actual page , not the one saying that my registration has been completed

Comment: `r.status_code` could be interesting as well.

Comment: It could be javascript. You could try the dryscrape library (almost identical to requests), which will deal with that for you.

Comment: So i was still looking for solution. Actually I need to send a post to 2 different domain. One of them has a token --> Request URL:https://www.createsend com/t/securedsubscribe?token=C49F2F17C3B29BD83F3B5081EBECBED80C806B5D6FED1403E03C55D49E617897E1D06B59118FFB1A
It changes everytime , just wondering how can i predict it or recover it ?